# CVPixelBufferRef: Video Buffer and Depth Buffer have different orientations

Tags: ios, orientation, cvpixelbuffer, truedepth-camera, depth-camera

Right now I'm working with Depth camera at iOS since I want to measure distance to the camera of certain points at the frame.

I did all necessary setup in my camera solution and now I have two `CVPixelBufferRef` in my hands - one with pixel data and one with depth data.

This is how I fetch both buffers from `AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer`:

```
- (void)dataOutputSynchronizer:(AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer *)synchronizer didOutputSynchronizedDataCollection:(AVCaptureSynchronizedDataCollection *)synchronizedDataCollection
{
    
    AVCaptureSynchronizedDepthData *syncedDepthData = (AVCaptureSynchronizedDepthData *)[synchronizedDataCollection synchronizedDataForCaptureOutput:depthDataOutput];
    AVCaptureSynchronizedSampleBufferData *syncedVideoData = (AVCaptureSynchronizedSampleBufferData *)[synchronizedDataCollection synchronizedDataForCaptureOutput:dataOutput];
    
    if (syncedDepthData.depthDataWasDropped || syncedVideoData.sampleBufferWasDropped) {
        return;
    }
    
    AVDepthData *depthData = syncedDepthData.depthData;
    CVPixelBufferRef depthPixelBuffer = depthData.depthDataMap;
    
    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = syncedVideoData.sampleBuffer;
    
    if (!CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer)) {
        return;
    }
    //... code continues
}
```

Before getting any depth data, I decided to check if dimensions of my buffers align. And I have found out, that my `buffer with pixel data` has dimensions `480x640` (vertical, like the orientation of my app) and `buffer with depth data` has dimensions `640x480` (horizontal).

Obviously, buffers are different and I can not match pixels to depth values. Do I need to rotate my depth buffer somehow? Is this a known issue?

Please advise how should I solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I too see it, Hope this helps. Angle in radians.

```
extension CVPixelBuffer {
    func transformedImage(targetSize: CGSize, rotationAngle: CGFloat) -> CIImage? {
        let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: self, options: [:])
        let scaleFactor = Float(targetSize.width) / Float(image.extent.width)
        return image.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)).applyingFilter("CIBicubicScaleTransform", parameters: ["inputScale": scaleFactor])
    }
}
```

caller side: I used angle as: -(.pi/2)

```
let depthMap = pixelBuffer.transformedImage(targetSize: desiredSize, rotationAngle: -(.pi/2))
```